# Graph dfs runtime error

Tags: html, c++, algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

```
   #include<iostream>
   #include<vector>
   #include <iterator>
   #include<stdio.h>

   using namespace std;
   int t,i,u,v,f,e,a,b,flag=0,flag2=0;
   vector<bool> visited;
   int flag3=0;
   vector<vector<int> > graph;

   void dfs(int u)
   {
     visited[u]=true;
     printf("u=%d ",u);
     if(u==a)
     flag=1;
     if(u==b)
       flag2=1;
     if(flag==1&&flag2==1)
     {
       flag3=1;
     }

     for(vector<int>::iterator it=graph[u].begin();it!=graph[u].end();it++)
     {
        if(!visited[*it])
        dfs(*it);
     }
   }

   int main()
   {
     cin>>t;
     printf("%d",t);
     int j;
     for(j=0;j<t;j++)
     {
       cin>>f>>e>>a>>b;

       graph = vector<vector<int> > (f);
       for(i=1;i<=e;i++)
       {
         cin>>u>>v;
         //printf("%d %d\n",u,v);
          int old=u;
          while(1)
          {
            u=v;
            v=u+old;
            if(v>f)
              break;
            //printf("l2 u=%d v=%d\n",u,v);
            graph[u].push_back(v);
            graph[v].push_back(u);
            //printf("%d %d\n",u,v);
          }
          //printf("l1 u=%d v=%d\n",u,v);
        }
        for(i=0;i<f;i++)
            visited[i]=false;

        for(i=0;i<f;i++)
        {
          if(visited[i]==true)
          {
            cout<<visited[i]<<endl;
            continue;
          }
          flag=0;
          flag2=0;
          printf("\n");
          dfs(i);
        }
        if(flag3==1)
          printf("It is possible to move the furniture.\n");
        else
          printf("The furniture cannot be moved.\n");
        printf("%d\n",j);
      }
      return 0;
     }
```

This is the code for the problem at http://www.spoj.com/problems/SCRAPER/.

I used dfs to solve the problem with C++ vectors.

For the test case

```
1
1000 2 500 777
2 3
2 1
```

Or any other test case I am getting a SIGSEVG error. Why?

Suppose `u=3`, `v=5` so edges would be 5,8 and 8,11 and 11,14 etc. until the 2nd term is less than the vertex count.

Comment: Did you try running it in a debugger?

Comment: `int t,i,u,v,f,e,a,b,flag=0,flag2=0;` You lost me here. Give your variables *meaningful* names if you want people to read your code.

Comment: f is no.of verticess,e= no of edges,u=interval,v=starting point,

Comment: suppose u=3,v=5 so edges would be 5,8 and 8,11 and 11,14 etc until 2nd term is less than vertex count

Comment: global variables are evil

Comment: @ayushnigam By sisgev do you mean SIGSEGV? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023882/linux-how-to-debug-a-sigsegv-how-do-i-trace-the-error-source

Answer (score 0):

You have a global variable

```
vector<bool> visited;
```

which you access in various places e.g.

```
if(visited[i]==true)
...
if(!visited[*it])
```

Nowhere do you make it big enough for the nodes in your graph.

---

**EDIT**

For the graph itself, you have made it large enough to hold `f` items:

```
graph = vector<vector<int> > (f);
```

Doing likewise with `visited` might help:

```
visited = vector<bool> (f);
```

I suspect there are other problems loitering in here, but that's not going to help.

Comment: am not making it big enough for nodes??what are u trying to say ..please be clear